# spark strucutred streaming 2.3.0 | Read Avro Kafka Topic | Required attribute 'value' not found;

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to read an Avro Topic ,Schema described alongside in schema registry.Unable to deserialize and write the avro topic in string format into another kafka Topic neither by conventional methods nor using latest from_avro methods. code as in below. Please share your expertise.

```
Program
def main(args: Array[String]) {
 val spark = 
 SparkSession.builder().appName("KafkaAvroReader")
 .master("local[2]").getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val envConf = ConfigFactory.load.getConfig(args(0))

val consumer_grp = args(2)
val topics = args(1)

   val kafkaParams = Map[String, String](
  "kafka.bootstrap.servers" -> envConf.getString("bootstrap.server"),
  "key.deserializer" -> "KafkaAvroDeserializer",
  "value.deserializer" -> "KafkaAvroDeserializer",
  ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG -> "consumer_grp",
  ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG -> "earliest",
  "failOnDataLoss" -> "false",
  "schema.registry.url" -> envConf.getString("schemaRegistryURL"))

val subjectValueName = topics + "-value"

 val avro_schema = new RestService(envConf.getString("schemaRegistryURL")).getLatestVersion(subjectValueName)
val messageSchema = new Schema.Parser().parse(avro_schema.getSchema).toString
val kafkaAVroTopic_Df = 
spark.readStream.format("Kafka").option("subscribe", 
topics).options(kafkaParams).load()
kafkaAVroTopic_Df.printSchema
val output = kafkaAVroTopic_Df.select(from_avro('value, 
messageSchema) as 'abc)
output.printSchema
output.
writeStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", 
envConf.getString("bootstrap.server")).
option("topic", "spark6Stream").option("checkpointLocation", 
"/user/cloudera/spkcheckpnt31").start()
  Depedencies
  <properties>
  <scala.version>2.11</scala.version>
 <spark.version>2.4.0</spark.version>
 <kafka.version>1.1.1</kafka.version>
 <confluent.version>5.0.0</confluent.version>
 <kafkaclients.version>1.0.1</kafkaclients.version>
 </properties>
 <dependencies>
 <dependency>
 <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
 <artifactId>kafka-streams-avro-serde</artifactId>
 <version>${confluent.version}</version>
 </dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka-connect-avro-converter</artifactId>
<version>${confluent.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka-schema-registry</artifactId>
<version>${confluent.version}</version>
</dependency>

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark- 
 streaming -->
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
 <artifactId>spark-streaming_${scala.version}</artifactId>
 <version>${spark.version}</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -- 
>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.version}</artifactId>
<version>${spark.version}</version>
</dependency>

 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark- 
 streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_${scala.version}</artifactId>
<version>${spark.version}</version>
</dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka -->
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
 <artifactId>kafka_${scala.version}</artifactId>
 <version>${kafka.version}</version>
 </dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka- 
 clients -->
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
 <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
 <version>${kafkaclients.version}</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>${spark.version}</version>
  </dependency>

   <!-- packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.0 -->
   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-avro_${scala.version}</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.0</version>

   </dependency>
   <!-- packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.0 -->
   <dependency>
   <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-avro_${scala.version}</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.0</version>
```

Error: screenshot attached as well
 ERROR Query [id = cd559067-939b-47f1-9cab-8268873fb210, runId = 22110ea8-858b-44c6-83c6-75ec7c77fcba] terminated with error (org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution:91)
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Required attribute 'value' not found;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$$anonfun$6.apply(KafkaWriter.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$$anonfun$6.apply(KafkaWriter.scala:71)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$.validateQuery(KafkaWriter.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.createStreamWriter(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:502)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJrQh.png)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: Required attribute 'value' not foun

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when Spark 2.2.0 standalone mode write Dataframe to local single-node Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46454014/error-when-spark-2-2-0-standalone-mode-write-dataframe-to-local-single-node-kafk)

Comment: Can you include the output from `output.printSchema`? I think the error is due to missing `value` column that you remove when `select(from_avro('value, 
messageSchema) as 'abc)`. If you change `as 'abc` to `as 'value` the query should be fine.