# Spark Structured Streaming code has issues reading json in java, something similar works on spark2-shell in scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

Program:

```
public class KafkaSinkListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws StreamingQueryException {

        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("ABHISEK_APP").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate(); 
        spark.sparkContext().setLogLevel("WARN");

        Dataset<Row> rawDF = spark.readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "<host:port values here>")
                .option("subscribe", "ERROR_TOPIC")
                .option("kafka.max.poll.records", "4")
                .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
                .load();

        Dataset<Row> kafkaValuesDS = rawDF.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)"); 
        DataType schema = getSimpleSchema();

        Dataset<Row> actionNestedDS = kafkaValuesDS.select(functions.from_json(functions.col("value"), schema).as("jsonmain"));
        Dataset<Row> actionDS = actionNestedDS.select("jsonmain.*"); //or selectExpr

        DataStreamWriter<Row> query = actionDS.writeStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "<Same host:port values here>")
                .option("topic", "KAFKA_SINKED_TOPIC")
                .option("checkpointLocation", "/abhisek/test/kafkasink_checkpoint")
                .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
                .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("25 seconds"));

        query.start().awaitTermination();

    }


    private static DataType getSimpleSchema() {
        return DataTypes.createStructType(
                new StructField[]{
                        DataTypes.createStructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, false),
                        DataTypes.createStructField("marks", DataTypes.IntegerType, false),
                        DataTypes.createStructField("action", DataTypes.StringType, false),
                        DataTypes.createStructField("time", DataTypes.TimestampType, false)
                }
        );
    }       
}
```

Something similar in Scala works fine on spark2-shell but gives following error when I run this program:

```
20/01/15 14:36:44 ERROR streaming.MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = 92f6a87d-7426-4809-8f9d-75e01ab1c78b, runId = 777fb3bb-9380-4cae-a769-95f4fa8c5537] ter                                        minated with error
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Required attribute 'value' not found;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$$anonfun$6.apply(KafkaWriter.scala:71)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$$anonfun$6.apply(KafkaWriter.scala:71)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$.validateQuery(KafkaWriter.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.createStreamWriter(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch(MicroBatchE                                        xecution.scala:443)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecu                                        tion.scala:133)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.sc                                        ala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.sc                                        ala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.sc                                        ala:279)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: Required attribute 'value' not found;
```

Scala similar code for from_json which works fine:

```
val schema = new StructType().add("name", StringType).add("marks", IntegerType).add("action", StringType).add("time", TimestampType)
val simpleSchema = new StructType().add("value", StringType)

val actionData = "{\"name\":\"Abhisek\",\"marks\":50,\"action\":\"Open\",\"time\":1469501675}"
    val data = Seq(Row(actionData))
    val simpleKafkaDF = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data), simpleSchema)


 scala> val expDS1 = simpleKafkaDF.select(from_json(col("value"), schema) as "jsonmain")
expDS1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [jsonmain: struct<name: string, marks: int ... 2 more fields>]

val flatDS1 = expDS1.select("jsonmain.*")

scala> flatDS1.show(false)
+-------+-----+------+-------------------+
|name   |marks|action|time               |
+-------+-----+------+-------------------+
|Abhisek|50   |Open  |2016-07-25 22:54:35|
+-------+-----+------+-------------------+
```

Without the json issue, the java program runs fine.
Spark version is 2.3.0.cloudera3 and Kafka is 0.10.*

Comment: does this solution apply for problem?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46454014/error-when-spark-2-2-0-standalone-mode-write-dataframe-to-local-single-node-kafk

Comment: Got your point @nonono, My mistake I assumed the issue with something else. Works like charm. Feeling silly. Would reduce the program in question for brewity.

Comment: Closing the question as its almost duplicate of already asked question which I missed.